# Specify number of copies when printing pages in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying, in Word VBA, to display a pop-up asking the user how many copies of pages 1 to 2 should be printed, and then print those pages in the requested number of copies.
All other pages, starting from page 3, should be printed only once.

I get

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

```vb
Sub PrintPages()
    ' Popup anzeigen und Anzahl der Kopien abfragen
    Dim copies As Integer
    Dim userInput As String
    
    ' Benutzerabfrage und Umwandlung in Integer
    userInput = InputBox("Wie viele Kopien möchten Sie von den Seiten 1 bis 2 drucken?", "Drucken von Seiten 1 bis 2")
    If IsNumeric(userInput) Then
        copies = CInt(userInput)
    Else
        MsgBox "Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Zahl ein."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Seiten 1 bis 2 in der angegebenen Anzahl drucken
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, From:=1, To:=2, Copies:=copies

    ' Alle anderen Seiten nur einmal drucken
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintRangeFromTo, From:=3, To:=ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1, Copies:=1
End Sub
```

I tried converting the user input to an integer using the `CInt()` function, as suggested in some online resources.
I keep getting

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `wdPrintFromTo` if you're using the `From` and `To` parameters, if you want `wdPrintRangeOfPages` you need to use the `Pages` parameter.

`From`, `To`, and `Pages` all accept strings, not numbers.

`Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="1", To:="2", copies:=copies`

Or

`ActiveDocument.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Pages:="1-2", Copies:=copies`

As an aside `wdPrintRangeFromTo` is not a valid constant.